# Who says angels have (only) male genitals?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mysticism-kabbalah, sexuality, malach-angel

At some point whilst reading up on the imagery of angels, I came across an essay detailing how at least one Rabbi in history claimed (as far as I remember) that angels basically came either with male genitals or no genitals at all - never with female genitals - and these two sets of angels were essentially on different 'levels'.

I cannot remember who it was, nor can I find it now. I don't even remember if it was referring to Talmud, Kabbalah, or whatever.
Does anyone have any clue about this? Either who said it, a Midrash on it, or has anyone read a similar essay?
(Editing re' comments: Magen Avraham apparantly cites Midrash Rabbah, Devarim, parasha 2, Va'etchanan and Yalkut Shimonei to Mishlei 21:22 on this, but apparently there is 'another separate Midrash' establishing all angels as male? https://theedencenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Leelah-article.pdf)

(Just to be clear, I'm aware that we often think of angels as genderless/sexless, and that simultaneously we have imagery in the Tanakh and Talmud labelling angels as 'men' or 'women' at certain points, or implying it by grammar, such as the name of Lailah - although apparently this is contested and some say Lailah is regarded as 'male' despite the name. Also, there was no mention of demons in the essay.)

Comment: Why the sexuality tag?

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii 
Because there's no tag for 'genitals' (can't make my own yet) and the query overlaps with concepts around sex and gender (E.g: Rabbi Eliezer Waldenberg on angels and gender/sex reassignment and marriage).

Comment: Talmud (Gittin 68a) mentions: שידה ושידתין - שד זכר ושד נקבה (male and female demons).

Comment: Magen Avraham (OC 610:5) https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.610.5?lang=bi

Comment: @IsraelReader 
Thankyou, but neither of these seem to be it. The Rabbi I read about explicitly stated that only angels who were genderless or male (as in explicitly having penises) existed on these levels - No females, which is what the Gittin mentions, and the Magen Avraham just seems to mention women being like 'male shepherding angels', and I can't find anything else on R. Gombiner focusing on angels, much less their genitalia.

Comment: See Talmud (Chagigah 16a) that demons reproduce in a manner like humans do.

Comment: @IsraelReader Yes, thankyou, I've seen that before. The writings I'm trying to find did not mention demons at all, nor reproduction. It was solely focusing on two particular levels of angels - One all male and one genderless, establishing that there were explicitly no female angels (at least at this level).

Comment: See Vayikra Rabbah 31 based on Proverbs 21:22

Comment: @שלום 
Thankyou. That doesn't seem to be it either, but I'll try referencing from it as a start point.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the Magen Avraham. He does not say that women are like male shepherding angels. To the contrary, he says that women can't even attempt to emulate angels, due to the fact that angels are all male, and they're female. [See Midrash quoted by מחצית השקל (ad loc.), שו"ת מנחת אלעזר (ח"ב, סי' סד)].

Comment: @IsraelReader I see. Thanks. It might be a starting point - I'll keep looking with Yom Kippur as a reference - but could you please send me a link to the Midrash in English? My Hebrew is really bad and it makes looking anything like that up very difficult.

Comment: @שלום 
It probably was linked to that at some point. On the other hand, it dismisses Zechariah's stork-winged women, which was what intrigued me. The problem is I don't recall the essay referencing a particular line of Tanach, Talmud, or anything... It was pretty long and explicitly detailed, but the only bit that stuck with me was about there being at least two levels of angels discussed, and that they only came as male (literally mentioning penises in the essay) or sexless. You'd think that would be enough for me to find it, but nope. :(